# Run a EXE on a machine restart on a Windows 2008 Server where UAC is enabled

Tags: exe, windows-server-2008-r2, uac, app-startup

I have an exe which runs as a start-up process on a system restart. On a machine where UAC is enabled, it is blocking the start of my exe.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You should probably implement it as a system service rather than as an ordinary application.  Or, if it doesn't need administrator privilege, make sure the manifest is configured to asInvoker rather than requiresAdmin.

Comment: My Application is not a right candidate to be a system service because it is  a tool which is used by the user only to perform a certain task which involve couple of restarts.

Comment: OK, so if it's a user application then you choose the second option: make sure it has a manifest, and that the manifest is configured to asInvoker rather than requiresAdmin.  If you're using Visual Studio, those options are under Linker -> Manifest File.

Comment: If you are asking if you can dynamically bypass the UAC prompt, the answer is no. The prompt exists for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the Windows task scheduler to run the application on windows startup. 
The below link has the steps [Click here](http://www.7tutorials.com/use-task-scheduler-launch-programs-without-uac-prompts)

Or you can write some code using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll to setup the startup task using Windows scheduler

Comment: This isn't an ideal approach in general, because it won't work if the logged-on user doesn't have admin privilege.  But it is suitable for some situations.

Comment: Yes Harry, this approach will work only for Admin users.

Comment: Sorry for commenting late, thank you for the answer i implemented the same and its working fine:)